# How to catch Keyboard and mouse events?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I want to create an application. This application has to do something when a user presses special keys on keyboard or/and uses scroll wheel. This application is a service. It has no windows. I want to catch any keyboard or mouse events which were designed with other applications.

For example, you are watching TV by 3rd party application. If you press `Ctrl + Shift` and use scroll wheel my application changes the volume.

I use Windows 7 x64 and Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 4):

You can call [SetWindowsHookEx()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990(VS.85).aspx) to be notified when various events occur. You probably want to use the keyboard hook and the mouse hook to watch for mouse events.

Comment: It's not clear. I call `hhk=::SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, LowLevelKeyboardProc1, 0, 0);`. But this does not work. Could you give me more info?

Comment: It would probably be better to use the normal keyboard hook and the mouse hook. The low level keyboard hook might be called too early - I'm not sure if it will give you the info you need, or not. There seems to be an example linked from the MSDN page - maybe that will help?

Comment: Note that the _LL hooks require that you have a GetMessage()/DispatchMessage() loop even if you do not have any visible windows; if you just Sleep() or Wait...(), then it won't work. Since you're on x64, note that _LL hooks work against both 32- and 64-bit apps, but the normal hooks only get loaded into a process that has the same bitness, so a 32-bit process will only get events from other 32-bit processes, and similar for 64-bit.

Answer (score 3):

If your application is a true Win32 service, then on Vista and beyond, the application won't receive keyboard or mouse events - to close a security hole (search for "shatter attack"), Microsoft isolated all services to prevent them from interacting with the user.

You'll need to have your application run in the session with the interactively logged on user.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the RAW INPUT method, It is more reliable than GetAsyncKeyState etc.

I wrote [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/297312/Minimal-Key-Logger-using-RAWINPUT) on Code Project that may be of use to you.

There is both C# and a MASM source code versions available.