# get mouse coordinates when user press Ctrl and click

Tags: c++, windows

I want to get mouse click coordinates X and Y when user press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and click at same time. 
User may click anywhere on the screen or programs. I want my program to catch the event and get coordinates when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key is down pressed and mouse click occurs at same time. I want to get system coordinates X and Y, not the window coordinates of other programs.
I'm using C++ .

How to do that ?

Windows OS, WIN API code

I'm doing next which is not working:

```
HHOOK MouseHook;
LRESULT CALLBACK MouseHookProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){

        PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT k = (PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT)(lParam);
        POINT p;


        if(wParam == WM_RBUTTONDOWN)
        {
          // right button clicked
          GetCursorPos(&p);
          //p.x 
          //p.y
          //my program is never getting here, why ?
        }

}
 MouseHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL,(HOOKPROC)MouseHookProc,0,0);
```

if I change the above line to:   `MouseHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE,(HOOKPROC)MouseHookProc,GetModuleHandle(NULL),0);`
then it will work only for my own program window, but not hooking clicks outside of my program

Comment: On what system? Which GUI toolkit are you using?

Comment: Windows OS, WIN API code , is that possible ? thanks

Comment: This is related to [How to catch Keyboard and mouse events?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2664391/172695).

Comment: yes, but it is not clear

Comment: @user3146513 - not clear how to use `SetWindowsHookEx()`?

Comment: no, check my post code, it not working for me, whats wrong ?

Comment: @user3146513 I've edited my answer like below.

Comment: I remember having the same problem with keyboard input before. It was only able to capture input in other applications when the program was running as administrator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you read this article? [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644986%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

First of all, if you want to catch system entire mouse + keyboard event, your hooking function must be placed on a dll.

1)If nCode is less than zero, the hook procedure must return the value returned by CallNextHookEx.
Like below,

```
if(nCode < 0)
{ 
   CallNextHookEx(hook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
   return 0;
}
```

If `CallNextHookEx` is not called, there is a chance that other processes that have installed hook may not get the events correctly.

2)And then, check `nCode` again, whether it is `HC_ACTION`.

```
switch (nCode) 
{ 
  case HC_ACTION:
     ...
```

3)Finally, you can check `WPARAM` for `WM_RBUTTONDOWN`, and `LPARAM` for `MSLLHOOKSTRUCT`

Comment: The OP is trying to get the events of all applications, not his own.

Comment: It's not working, i did created a DLL and it is working only for main Window of my program, but not hook mouse click outside my window. send me your  code ?

Comment: @user3146513 If your hook only work in your program, your hook may be faild to be global hook. In your code, `MouseHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE,(HOOKPROC)MouseHookProc,GetModuleHandle(NULL),0);`. This `GetModuleHandle(NULL)` means current process, not your hook dll. So you have to use like this. `HMODULE hMod = GetModuleHandle("your_hook.dll"); MouseHook = SetWindowHookEx(WH_MOUSE,(HOOKPROC)MouseHookProc, hMod, 0);`

Comment: I also write very useful link [here1](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1037/Hooks-and-DLLs), [here2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/67091/Mouse-and-KeyBoard-Hooking-utility-with-VC). These articles have sample source as well. I hope you solve to problem successfully.

Comment: I vote up your answer, but it not worked for me , I don't know why

Answer (score 0):

The way I would approach is I would create a global variable say

```
int ctrl_pressed = 0 
/* 
0 -- ctrl nt pressed
1 -- Crtl Pressed
*/
```

Step 1: Now I would handle both WM_KEYDOWN and WM_KEYUP for ctrl

Step 2: In the callback of `WM_KEYDOWN (if lparam is ctrl )` I would set ctrl_pressed to 1.
And in case of `WM_KEYUP` I would set `ctrl_pressed to 0.`

Step 3: Now Finally ill handle `WM_MOUSECLICKED`
and then check if `ctrl_pressed(global) is 1` , which if true I can just get the coordinates.

This is just an approach may be not the most efficient solution. 
Wait for more experienced WIN32 Developers to give their input on this.

Comment: The OP is trying to get the events of all applications, not his own.

Comment: Opps srry .. ! thn u need hooks.. use SetWindowHookEx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx